# Elixir/Distillery: Remote IP Address Isn't Accurate In Deployed Applications

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, distillery

For testing, I have a simple controller to inspect the client's remote IP address:

```
defmodule AppWeb.PageController do
  use AppWeb, :controller

  def index(conn, _params) do
    IO.inspect conn.remote_ip

    render conn, "index.html"
  end
end
```

While testing in my production environment with `phx.server`, `conn.remote_ip` contains the expected client IP address, which is in this format:

```
{0, 0, 0, 0}
```

While running the binary packaged with Distillery, `conn.remote_ip` returns something like this instead, even for multiple remote clients with different IP addresses, it returns the same thing every time:

```
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12345, 12345, 12345}
```

My application isn't sitting behind a reverse proxy, so what else might be causing this to happen?

Comment: Is it possible to run `iex` on remote server and do call `conn.remote_ip` manually?

Comment: Could it be that your production system uses IPv6 ? Just a guess...